# ExtJs dropdown list with two color rows

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have ExtJs combo drop down list. I want to two-color(odd as red and even as green)row list when combo is span

Note: single row has multi(more than one line) lines

1. Is this possible with ExtJS 4.2? if yes how can i do that.

   ```
                                   {       xtype: 'combobox',
                                           id: 'mycbo',
                                           itemId: 'mycbo',
                                           fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                           name: 'id',
                                           tabIndex: 5,
                                           allowBlank: false,
                                           displayField: 'NAME',
                                           forceSelection: true,
                                           queryMode: 'local',
                                           store: 'STORE',
                                           valueField: 'ID'
                                       },
   ```

Comment: Can you share what code you have written so far please

Comment: i added combobox  code

Comment: What do you mean 'when combo is span'? Are you just trying to shade the list items as alternate colours?

Comment: yes. 'span' mean uncollapse(that happen just click on combo box after that list all items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `listConfig` config to change behaviour of combobox picker. (For more information: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig)

In snippet below I'm setting class `'odd'` and `'even'` to each option in the combobox. Then I can style it with CSS.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {
           return '<tpl if="xindex%2==0"><div class="odd"></tpl><tpl  if="xindex%2==1"><div class="even"></tpl> {' + displayField + '} </div>';
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Custom Item Templates example here - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/form/combos.html and look at the source code and how the listConfig is used.

You should be able to use this approach for achieving custom styling of the list items that appear